# CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES on Nvidia Quadro M2000M

Tags: opencl, nvidia

Yesterday i got to run the unit tests of our current application on the new notebooks and got the CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES error doing so. The code itself runs without errors on ATI cards or Intel CPU's.

The thing that got me suspicious is that the M2000M supports 'OpenCL 1.2 CUDA'. Is this standard 'OpenCL 1.2' or does it differ and do i need to modify the code?

Here the code:

```
__kernel void pointNormals(__global const uint* cellLinkIds, __global const uint* cellLinks,
                                    __global const float3* cellnormals, __global float3* pointnormals,
                                    const uint nrPoints)
{
    const uint gid = get_global_id(0);
    if(gid < nrPoints)
    {
        const uint first = select(cellLinkIds[gid-1], (uint)0, gid==0);
        const uint last = cellLinkIds[gid];

        float3 pointnormal = (float3)0.f;

        for(uint i = first; i < last; ++i)
        {
            pointnormal += cellnormals[cellLinks[i]];
        }

        pointnormals[gid] = normalize(pointnormal);
    }
}
```

/edit:
In the tests i get 6 errors, first at the call of `clWaitForEvents` the others are from `clEnqueueWriteBuffer`

Comment: "OpenCL 1.2 CUDA" is standard OpenCL 1.2. Which API returned CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES? You're showing kernel code but only host APIs return that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the cause ...

the line with `const uint first = select(cellLinkIds[gid-1], (uint)0, gid==0);` caused invalid memory access when `gid` is `0` (first element afaik).

fixed ith with `const uint first = gid == 0 ? (uint)0 : cellLinkIds[gid - 1];`. but what i dont get is why AMD cards did work with that bug and Nvidia did return an error.

Comment: NVIDIA is more strict checking memory access in GPU, AMD is not. It happened to me multiple times on AMD to have a system reboot running buggy kernels, so it is not a good thing believe me..

Comment: we did run this code over a year without issues on AMD cards ... but its good to know that NVIDIA is more strict ... so dev on them should fix all problems that would be 'ignored' by AMD cards